# How to scroll to element which is not visible in iOS using appium

Tags: ios, automation, appium, dom-events, java-client

I was using the following code to scroll to an element which is not visible:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElementByName("text");

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        HashMap<String, String> scrollObjects = new HashMap<String, String>();
        scrollObjects.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
        js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObjects);
```

I am getting below error when I use above method for scrolling:-

> Unknown command, all the mobile commands except scroll have been removed.

In **Appium [1.5.0](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.5.0)** , name locator is removed

In **java-client [v4.0.0](https://github.com/appium/java-client/releases/tag/4.0.0)**, `scrollTo()` and `scrollToExact()` became deprecated.

I am using xpath instead of `findElementByName()`.

What is the workaround for mobile: scrollTo

Comment: have you tried to make the element visible by  drive.swipe() method or using move to element location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer for this issue. Use element and direction as arguments to scroll method.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElementByName("text");

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

HashMap scrollObjects = new HashMap();
scrollObjects.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
scrollObjects.put("direction", "down");
driver.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObjects );
```

References:- https://pioneer2k9.blogspot.in/2016/08/mobile-scroll-command-is-not-working-in_4.html